# Wso2 Integration Studio - RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value while consuming message from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, avro, confluent-schema-registry, wso2-integration-studio

I need to configure an inbound kafka from integration studio that can read from a topic and deserialize incoming data via schema registry (AVRO) ,
below i leave the configuration i am currently using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint class="org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer" name="KAFKAListenerEP" onError="fault" sequence="kafka_process_seq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="interval">10</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.behavior">polling</parameter>
        <parameter name="key.deserializer">org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer</parameter>
        <parameter name="value.deserializer">io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer</parameter>
        <parameter name="topic.name">nome-topic</parameter>
        <parameter name="poll.timeout">100</parameter>
        <parameter name="bootstrap.servers">server....</parameter>
        <parameter name="group.id">group-id</parameter>
        <parameter name="contentType">application/json</parameter>
        <parameter name="class">org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer</parameter>
        <parameter name="sasl.mechanism">PLAIN</parameter>
        <parameter name="security.protocol">SASL_SSL</parameter>
        <parameter name="sasl.jaas.config">configuration;</parameter>
        <parameter name="schema.registry.url">http....ecc</parameter>
        <parameter name="schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info">user:password</parameter>
        <parameter name="subject.name.strategy">io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy</parameter>
        <parameter name="schema.registry.auto.register.schemas">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

### ------stacktrace------
ERROR {KafkaMessageConsumer} - Error while consuming the message org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition partitionName at offset 12345678. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.

[image: lib directory]

the problem i am experiencing is during data acquisition.
What I am sure of is that I can connect to the topic but for some reason the data is not being converted.

I have also tried leaving a StringDeserializer also for the value and as contentType a plain/text but what I get is a 'corrupted' string.

I am not sure if my configuration is correct but unfortunately I have not found many examples .
I apologize in advance if my request is not very clear, and I thank anyone who can also give me a hand.

Comment: Can you add the full exception?

Comment: i add the stacktrace and the lib directory

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of the inbound consumer did not support basic Auth for schema registry.

A new version of the inbound endpoint has been released by WSO2 with support for the basic credentials (org.apache.synapse.kafka.poll-1.1.1.jar).

Use the below propeties to configure the connection

```
<parameter name="basic.auth.credentials.source">USER_INFO</parameter>
<parameter name="basic.auth.user.info">username:password</parameter>
```